# Does one string contain another in fish shell?

Tags: variable, string, fish

I am working on my fish.config for using the [fish shell](http://fishshell.com).

I am trying to compare strings using bash syntax but fish doesn't accept the syntax. There is clearly another way to do it. Any suggestions for a solution as clean as the bash solution below?

```
if [[ $STRING == *"other_string"* ]]; then
    echo "It contains the string!"
fi
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks to me like there's a `string` function for that purpose:

```
$ set STRING something here
$ string match -q "other_string" $STRING; and echo yes
$ set STRING some other_string here
$ string match -q "other_string" $STRING; and echo yes
yes
```

Or:

```
if string match -q "other_string" $STRING
  echo it matches
else
  echo is does not match
end
```